# How to get old Git branches onto GitHub?

Tags: git, github, branch, version-tree

I uploaded my git revisioned project to GitHub. From there I can see all my previous commits, but not the old branches.

Should I also push my local .git directory for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No (and note that "upload" doesn't really mean anything in the Git world.)

If you have other local branches, you need to explicitly push them (try `git push --all`).

Comment: Fixed the terminology. Thank you.